# Exception raised copying git repository folder

Tags: c#, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

sometimes it happens that while my application is copying the `git` repository folder file by file, I have this kind of exception when an other thread wants to do some operation on the repository, as for example knowing the `Head` value.

The exception is `System.AccessViolationException` and the stack trace is the following:

```
in LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_reference_lookup(git_reference*& reference, git_repository* repo, String name)
in LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_reference_lookup(RepositoryHandle repo, String name, Boolean shouldThrowIfNotFound) in c:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:riga 1932
in LibGit2Sharp.ReferenceCollection.Resolve[T](String name) in c:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\ReferenceCollection.cs:riga 441
in LibGit2Sharp.Repository.get_Head() in c:\projects\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Repository.cs:riga 268
in GitManager.get_CurrentBranch() in C:\Repository\MyProject\GitRepositoryManagement\GitManager.cs:riga 80
```

I don't know why this happens..any help is really appreciated!!! Thanks.

Comment: Permission Issues. Is it just that file?

Comment: @Will what other exception details do you need?

Comment: @SCramphorn I don't think it's a permission issues. If I copy the entire folder when I know that the other thread is not doing anything, everything works.

Comment: What version of LibGit2Sharp are you using?  Can you please upgrade to the latest version (v0.24) and see if this persists?

Comment: @EdwardThomson The LibGit2Sharp installed version is already 0.24.0

Comment: Interesting.  Did this just start happening after you upgraded to 0.24?  Or has this happened before?

Or is this a new app and you've only used 0.24.  If the latter, can you downgrade and see what happens?  We explicitly changed the behavior of locked files recently, and I'm wondering if that's causing problems.  But _nothing_ should cause an AccessViolation. 

Answer (score 0):

This error means that another process is locking file or directory. It can happen at any filesystem operation in Windows, I have seen it while listing directory content for example. Since you mentioned that you are using several threads you probably should explicitly guard the repository access so that only one thread is accessing it at a time. If the another process is not yours, you could look for possible conflicting process with `procmon` utility, for example.

Comment: That's not what a `System.AccessViolationException` is.  A `System.AccessViolationException` occurs when you try to write to memory that you don't own.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx